# how to make pins correspond to coordinates from shapes in Google Maps API v3

Tags: api, maps

I want to have a few pins, and then a rectangle on a map. All the pins should be inside the boundary of the rectangle. I know the coordinates of the pin, and the SW and NE of the rectangle.

My issue is: the pins start to be in the rectangle only for really zoomed in maps, and out of it when the map is zoomed out. This is really weird, as the coordinates don't change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got the anchor points of the pins set right?